# Double pointer doesn't get malloc'd in function

Tags: c, gdb

So I'm working in C and I have an `int **` inside of one function that is modified within another function. I was getting a SegFault when I was running this problem so I decided to debug it with `gdb`. What I found was that memory was never allocated to this array. My functions are like this

```
void declarer()
{
    int ** a;
    alocator(a, 4, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("%d\n", a[i][j]);
}

void alocator(int ** a, int b, int c)
{
    a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * b);
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c);
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            a[i][j] = j;
    }
}
```

When I run `gdb` with a breakpoint after the line `alocator(a, 4, 5)` (before the program segfaults), and I write `p a`, I get `$1 = (int **) 0x0` which shows that `a` is at address `0x0` and has no memory allocated for it. Why did `alocator` not allocate memory to it, and how can I get `alocator` to allocate memory to `a`?

Comment: because you pass `a` by value.

Comment: A "double pointer" is typically a `double *`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing `**a` by value, you have to pass it as pointer. So use a triple pointer:

```
void declarer()
{
    int **a;
    alocator(&a, 4, 5);
    ...
}

void alocator(int ***a, int b, int c)
{
    *a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * b);
    ...
```

Comment: In using this how do I assign `a[i]` and `a[i][j]`? Do I need to refer to them as `*a[i]` and `*a[i][j]` as well?

Comment: @EliSadoff Inside `allocator()` yes. Or `(*a)[i][j]`, I don't remember the order of precedence.

Comment: It's `(*a)[i][j]`

Answer (score 0):

You pass the variable `a` by value to the function, so its value won't be changed. You have two solutions:

Either change your function to accept value of type `int ***` and pass `a` by address, or change the return value of the function to `int **` and make use of that value upon invocation.

example:

```
void declarer()
{
    int ** a = alocator(4, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("%d\n", a[i][j]);
}

int **alocator(int b, int c)
{
    int **a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * b);
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c);
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            a[i][j] = j;
    }
    return a;
}
```